# $errors variable in laravel not available globally inside a function

Tags: php, laravel, view, helper

I am trying to make some helper functions i can use in Laravel 4 views

I will like to simply call `error_exists()` function to verify if validation was successful

So i made this:

```
function error_exists(){
    global $errors;
    if(!is_object($errors) && !method_exists($errors,'count')) return;
    //using MessageBag method called count()
    return $errors->count(); //which will return a boolean '0' if no error exists
}
```

The function `error_exists()` is always returning '`null`' because `$errors` seems not be available in global scope inside Laravel View

My controller looks like this:

```
//validator
$rules = array('username' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required');
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

// Validate the input and return correct response
if ($validator->fails()) Redirect::route('users.getLogin')->withErrors($validator);
```

NB: I can access `$errors` in views the only issue i have is how to access errors inside `error_exists()` function

Comment: You're just trying to see if there are any errors to show? Why not just use `$errors->any()`?

Comment: I know i can use `$errors->any()` but I will like to know why $errors is not available inside functions

Comment: Well, because as you say it's not global (globals are really bad). If you need it inside a function pass it as a parameter: `function error_exists($errors)`

Comment: Okay i get your point. I actually wanted to create other helper functions like `error($name)` which will be short for `$errors->first($name)`. Guest i will do without the helpers. :)  because `error($errors,$name)` is not what i want.

Comment: Ah what you want is certainly possible, but its a bunch more complex I'm afraid. You'd need to extend and modify a bunch of internal code - probably not worth it to be honest..

Comment: Its. Ok... Thanks all the same. KISS approach is better. Will do it the usual way.